# getting 404 in microsoft graph explorer for onedrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have logged into the graph explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer but when I try to retrieve a list of all files in my onedrive I get a 404 response, any ideas of why that is?

[image]

**update**, when I click the user account I see that I need to consent to permissions, and after I log on as the administrator I can consent to the permissions, but after I go back to the graph explorer and sign in with the user account (not the admin account) I still get the 404 error, and if I once more check the permissions they are gone?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to repo the same , and i am getting list of all items in OneDrive .You are getting "error 404  - Page Not Found" which you entered wrong URL , make sure you call correct URL - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children

[image]

Comment: yes I have the correct url......

Comment: provide us the request_id and timestamp of the error

Comment: "date": "2022-12-28T10:03:48",
            "request-id": "8a2cd379-24c7-486b-935b-54a3dc640b26",

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I had given the wrong permissions for this